# can't add columns in wxPython virtual grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython GUI with a very large grid.  I am using similar code to the [GridHugeTable.py](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/blob/master/demo/GridHugeTable.py)  example from the wxPython demo -- i.e., using PyGridTableBase to make a virtual grid.

I am running into trouble when I try to interactively add columns to this grid, however.

Calling `AppendCols(1)` results in this error:

```
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "Assert failure" failed at /Users/vagrant/pisi-64bit/tmp/wxPython-3.0.2.0-3/work/wxPython-src-3.0.2.0/src/generic/grid.cpp(1129) in AppendCols(): 
Called grid table class function AppendCols but your derived table class does not override this function
```

But if I try to overwrite `AppendCols` in my table class, the application just hangs indefinitely and never resolves.  It hangs even if there is actually nothing in my custom `AppendCols` method at all...

```
class HugeTable(gridlib.PyGridTableBase):

    """                                                                                                             
    Table class for virtual grid                                                                                    
    """

    def __init__(self, log, num_rows, num_cols):
        gridlib.PyGridTableBase.__init__(self)

    def AppendCols(self, *args):
        pass
```

I've been able to overwrite other methods successfully, (setValue, getValue, getColLabelValue, etc.), so I'm not sure what is different here.

**Update:**

I returned to this problem after a while away.  I no longer get the `wx.__core.PyAssertionError`.  However, I still can't get my custom AppendCols method to work.  I can't figure out what to put in AppendCols to make a new column *actually* show up.

I'm not sure how to look in the source code -- none of the Python documentation seems to have what I'm looking for, so maybe I need to go digging in wxWidgets?  The documentation hasn't helped:  https://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPyGridTableBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clue I needed is in the the demo code for [custom table](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/demo/GridCustTable.py).

So, this code works (leaving out my custom logic and just including the bare bones):

```
 def AppendCols(self, *args):
     msg = gridlib.GridTableMessage(self,  # The table                                               
                           gridlib.GRIDTABLE_NOTIFY_COLS_APPENDED, # what we did to it              
                           1)                                       # how many                      
    self.GetView().ProcessTableMessage(msg)
    return True
```